# Typescript confusion

Tags: typescript, angular

The following never seem to work when declaring or initializing data members in a class

```
var view: string[];
var view: string[] = [];
let view: string[];
let view: string[] = [];
```

despite the typescript docs saying that it should

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html

yet if I do

```
view: string[];

constructor() {
    this.view = [];
}
```

everything is fine.

Could someone please explain why

```
export class TextComponent implements OnInit {

   let view: string[] = [];        

    ngOnInit() {
    ....
    }
}
```

or any of the previously mentioned variants always results in an error of

```
ngOnInit is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put arbitrary code at the top-level of a class. You need to put it inside the constructor or a method.

Only field and method declarations are allowed outside the constructor or methdods.

```
export class TextComponent implements OnInit {

    view: string[] = [];        

    constructor() {
      var view: string[];
      var view: string[] = [];
      let view: string[];
      let view: string[] = [];
    }    
    ngOnInit() {
    ....
    }
}
```

I haven't tried if you declare the same variable multiple times (the code inside the constructor) but otherwise this way this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
export class TextComponent implements OnInit {

   let view: string[] = [];
```

This is a compile error (invalid syntax)!. Check the console.

## Fix

Use the correct syntax for class member initializer

```
export class TextComponent implements OnInit {

   view: string[] = [];
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html